# Bootstrap tags input with typeahead does not work

Tags: bootstrap-typeahead, bootstrap-tags-input

I want to restrict tags usage to only ones got from an API.

The ["Object as tags" example](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) seems to be what I'm looking for, but typeahead doesn't seem to work as expected (no placeholder opens)

```
<input id="tags" type="text">

<script>
  var tags = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: 'http://example.com/tags'
  });
  tags.initialize();

  $('input#tags').tagsinput({
    itemValue: 'id',
    itemText: 'name',
    typeahead: {
      name: 'tags',
      displayKey: 'name',
      source: tags.ttAdapter()
    }
  });
</script>
```

Here is some data returned from the API:

```
[
  {
    "name": "amazon",
    "createdAt": "2015-07-27T08:28:29.320Z",
    "updatedAt": "2015-07-27T08:28:29.320Z",
    "id": "55b5ebad3bbd894909b0eef5"
  },
  {
    "name": "android",
    "createdAt": "2015-07-27T08:28:29.398Z",
    "updatedAt": "2015-07-27T08:28:29.398Z",
    "id": "55b5ebad3bbd894909b0eef6"
  },
  {
    "name": "c-sharp",
    "createdAt": "2015-07-27T08:28:29.485Z",
    "updatedAt": "2015-07-27T08:28:29.485Z",
    "id": "55b5ebad3bbd894909b0eef7"
  },
  ...
]
```

I'm using Bootstrap 3.1.0, jQuery 1.10.2, Bootstrap Tags Input 0.4.2 and Typeahead 0.11.1.

Comment: If you want to restrict adding tags only with definite set of values maybe Bootstrap Multiselect is corresponding your needs more than Bootstrap Tags Input? Here is a [link](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/).

Comment: And [here](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) you can find more boosted version. I don't see any reasons to give user an opportunity to type some text in your case.

Comment: I'd rather use a tag library as StackOverflow does

Comment: try adding `data-role="tagsinput"` to your `input` tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap Tagsinput with Typeahead not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20774936/bootstrap-tagsinput-with-typeahead-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

```
var tags = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {
    url: 'http://example.com/tags',
    filter: function(response) {
      return response;
    }
  }
});
tags.initialize();
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation to your code snippet

Answer (score 0):

I saw a lot of issues with typeaheadjs and tagsinput.

After a lot of headaches, i found a solution.

Just remove these last lines on bootstrap-tagsinput.js :

```
$(function () {
$("input[data-role=tagsinput], select[multiple][data-role=tagsinput]").tagsinput();
});
```

The library code creates tagsinput data with no options, so your typeahead options will be ignored.